# How to return an integer from a class function from a certain number up to a certain number

Tags: python

Pretty new to Python here, I was working around classes up until I stumble upon creating a function under a class particularly with time that allows it to return an integer value from 0 up to, but not including, 24, indicating the closest hour to the starting
time of the event.

This is the code I have so far:

```
def get_time(self):
    """(int) Returns the integer time value"""
    for self._time in range(0, 24):
        return str(self._time)
```

I am not sure if I am meant to set an empty list before hand so I can refer to the index but I guess I'm stuck for now... when I test it this is what it's meant to output but this is what my code is outputting:

```
 - Event(My Event @ 0, True, False)
    ?               ^
    + Event(My Event @ 13, True, False)
    ?                  ^^
 :: __str__
```

Comment: Your `get_time` method doesn't make sense. It is trying perform a loop that sets the attribute `self._time` to each value from 0 to 23, but returns `str(self._time)` in the first iteration, so your `self._time` always gets set to zero, and the method always returns `'0'`. Whatever you meant it to do, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The return in your function will cause the for loop to end on its first iteration, which is why you are returning 0 every time. It is also slightly misleading that your comment specifies the function will return an integer even though it returns a string.
I am assuming you have set self._time somewhere and want to return the hour? Is self._time a datetime object? If so you can return self._time.hour, so your function would be

```
def get_time(self):
    """(int) Returns the integer time value"""
    return int(self._time.hour)
```